# iOS , Same UIButton with same selector on Multiple View Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, selector

I'm a newbie iOS developer, and I'm currently facing a problem.
I had to add the same UIButton manually on multiple View Controllers.
Now the code for creating it is repeated in every View Controller with that button.
Now I have to code the selector which is called by the button (An action sheet will be called) but I don't know if repeating the code in every controller is the best thing to do.
Is there a way to write only once the code for the action and call it from every view controller?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can create a UIButton Subclass and then add it to each view. The button behavior and properties will be stored in the class and that way you won't have to repeat it.

in xcode create a new file and choose objective c class and set the class name to MyButton or any other name, and set the subclass to UIButton.

Pay attention that in the subclass the UIButton is the `self` property. so when you wish to set it's properties you should use the self. for example:

```
self.tag = 1;
[self setImage:...];
//etc
```

Then in you view controllers you create MyButton like this:

```
MyButton *button = [[MyButton alloc]initWithFrame:...];
[self addSubView:button];
```